# Multiple count function in one table

Tags: mysql, sql

I want put multiple counts on the same table and the output should be in one table only using as 'name'.

```
select count(select count(TXN)
from sale1
where date(SALEDATE)=DATE(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY))) as c1, 
count(select count(TXN) from sale1 where RESPONSE='Y' date(SALEDATE)=DATE(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY))) as c2
 FROM sale1;
```

Comment: Attempting to format the SQL does not  make the intention any clearer.  Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: select 
count(case when date(SALEDATE)=DATE(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)) then 1 else 0 end) AS count1,
count(case when RESPONSE='Y' and date(SALEGDATE)=DATE(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)) then 1 else 0 end) AS count2
from sale;

Comment: I tried this but it is counting whole data i want only count of count(TXN)

Comment: I've tried to improve the question a bit.

Comment: What is the "count of count(TXN)"? If there are hundred records in the table, fourty of them having a value in TXN (the others have NULL), then `count(TXN)` is 40. So what is the "count" of this? 1, because 40 is only one number? But this is true for any number and hence completely independent from what is in the table. So: what is it *really* you want to count?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this
Count(Distinct TXN) 
it will give distinct count i.e. duplicate field it will count once.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand from your question you want to do several counts over data of the same table, I assume these two:

```
select count(TXN)
from sale1
where date(SALEDATE)=DATE(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY));
```

and

```
select count(TXN) from sale1 
where RESPONSE='Y' 
and date(SALEDATE)=DATE(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY);
```

Your query does not seem to be correct, and it seems you want to use the [`count`](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_count.asp) over a new query: `count(select ...)` but you cannot, `count` works over a list of rows of the current table.

You might want to do this to have the different count columns in the same output:

```
select sum(case when response='y' then 1 else 0 end) as yes_count,
sum(case when date(SALEDATE)=DATE(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) then 1 else 0 end) as day_interval_count
from sale1 
where response='y'
```

Here I use [`case when .. then .. end`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html) to generate either a 1 or 0 based on the row value, then with sum we do the count.

Another way is to make several queries which you could combine with [`union`](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp) to create two rows:

```
select count(x) as count
from sale1 
where response='y'
union
select count(x) as count
from sale1 
where response='n'
```